# Sculpting out a crease from a posed character

Tags: rigging, sculpting, rigify, sculpt

if I have this simple character posed with Rigify to finally be a 3D print, how do I sculpt out the crease at the back of the arm so there’s no issues when it comes to 3d printing?

[image]

Do I have to got into edit mode and remove the unwanted faces that fold into that area manually or is there a sculpt tool that will help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes you need to apply the Armature modifier, go in Edit mode and correct the topology to get rid of the inner faces. Sculpt won't help, except the Remesh tool if you're OK to use it (as it will change the mesh density)